# Mongo: data storage directory as read-only directory

Tags: mongodb

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to start mongodb:

> [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 20 Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /mnt/data/mng, terminating

I'm using centos 7.3 and I don't know if I can be an issue related with `se_linux`...

As you can see I'm set that mongo storage directory is on `/mnt/data/mng`. The problem seems to be related with some kind of permissions. I've took a look on there:

```
# ls -lha /mnt/data/
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root   root   17 Jun  1 10:01 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root   root   18 Jun  1 10:01 ..
drwxr-xr-x. 2 mongod mongod  6 Jun  1 10:01 mng
```

Here you can see the complete message:

```
I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=3373 port=30158 dbpath=/mnt/data/mng 64-bit host=localhost.localdomain
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.2
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 3f76e40c105fc223b3e5aac3e20dcd026b83b38b
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: rhel70
I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { command: [ "run" ], config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "localhost", port: 30158 }, processManagement: { fork: true, pidFilePath: "/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid" }, security: { authorization: "enabled" }, storage: { dbPath: "/mnt/data/mng", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log", quiet: true } }
I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 20 Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /mnt/data/mng, terminating
I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```